# Example of reducible representation without common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Can someone give an example of a reducible group representation $\varphi : G \rightarrow GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ with no common eigenvector among $\varphi(g)$ for all $g \in G$ ?

I'm looking for such a group because I just wrote the proof of the equivalence between irreducibility and no common eigenvector for the finite case. I want to know how does it look like when G is infinite but I don't see how to construct it.

Comment: Well if $\phi(g)$ has an eigenvector $v$ so does $\phi(1)$. Do you mean that there is no $v$ which is a $\phi(g)$ eigenvector for all $g\in G$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes that's it !

Comment: Why did you delete [this version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4109248/11619) rather than edit it to match with the question you really want to ask? You do know the rule that once you post something on this site, you cannot really delete it. Or rather, others can undelete it also.

Comment: How about the group consisting of all nonsingular $3 \times 3$ matrices $(a_{ij})$ with $a_{31}=a_{32}=0$, with $\phi$ the identity map? There is a $2$-dimensional invariant subspace, but no $1$-dimensional.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm sorry, I tought it would be better to post another question which would be clearer.

Comment: I commented there precisely so that you could fix the question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need $G$ to be infinite because otherwise Maschke's theorem tells us that the representations are fully decomposable. Hence if a 3-dimensional representation is not irreducible it will have a 1-dimensional subrepresentation consisting of shared eigenvectors.

An infinite example consists of the group of invertible $3\times3$ matrices of the shape
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}*&*&*\\ *&*&*\\ 0&0&*\end{array}\right).
$$
This group has the obvious 2-dimensional subrepresentation $V$ of consisting of the vectors $(x,y,0)^T$, $x,y$ arbitrary. But $V$ does not have a complementary 1-dimensional subrepresentation, so there are no shared eigenvectors.